# How to prevent the change of character position on selecting the content of html textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a textarea, and counting its characters, when it reaches multiple of 160 increment the message count, and on moving the cursor it will show the character position and the message number properly. but **on selecting the content it will display the message count as 0 and 0 remaining character**, how to solve this, i'm trying to set the values as last character on selecting the content.

Here is the working example of what I've tried : http://jsfiddle.net/F6CZs/1/

Any guidance and help is appreciated..!
Here is the actual values :

[image]

Here comes the change of values on selecting the content :
[image]

Comment: So, you're trying to get the position of the character within the textarea only when the number of characters within the textarea is 160 or more? In addition to that, you want to return the characters *after* the cursor position?

Comment: No, getPosition called after the jQuery binding click, keyup & keydown.And i dont' want to disable the text selection inside the textarea

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still confused. What are you attempting to do exactly?

Comment: Please type something inside the textarea and double click it for the selection of content. the value of remaining characters and messages become zero..

Comment: what i want is to display the last character values on selecting the text. I think the problem is on selecting the cursor position goes to first position.

Comment: Why don't you use `$('textarea').val().length` to get the number of characters in the text area?

Comment: I've tried it but i'm binding keydown elements so that by using the arrow keys it will show the the current cursor position and current message

Answer (score 0):

I got it it not be "keyup" it should be only

```
 $(id).bind("keydown click", function () {
```

Comment: it required because without using keyup bind the cursor position will display wrong answer

Comment: But @bios i checked it from your fiddle

Comment: please enter characters more than 160 you find the problem

Comment: Yes it will represent it as a second message,then what is problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F6CZs/2/ check this and click the last character and see the value, then move the arrow keys alternatively up and down it displays wrong values, that's why i added the keyup event, by logic you are right, but without keyup binding it dosen't work properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/U9vSF/1/

Not sure what you were trying to achieve with the, "# Message(s)" part of the counter.

Comment: "#Message(s)" part is used to display the total number of messages, its the modulus of the total character count by 160 and in your answer the on moving the cursor it doesn't display the the character/cursor position

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what you are trying to do. Sorry I couldn't help.